# Unity3D : How to hide touchscreen keyboard when i select inputfile and inputfield still focus

Tags: unity-game-engine, input-field

I've had this problem for a long time. I want to hide touchscreen keyboard when I select inputfile and inputfield still focus. I don't need touchscreen keyboard but I need `carretpostion` and `focus` on `inputfield`(application like calculator).

[image: What I want to accomplish]

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone for the answer. I solved the problem by custom inputfield. I disable touchscreen keyboard and get carretpostion by OnPointerUp .

code :

```js
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class InputFieldWithOutKeyboard : InputField
{

protected override void Start()
{
keyboardType = (TouchScreenKeyboardType)(-1);

}

public override void OnPointerDown(UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData)
{

base.OnPointerDown(eventData);
}

public override void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
{

Vector2 mPos;
RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(textComponent.rectTransform, eventData.position, eventData.pressEventCamera, out mPos);
Vector2 cPos = GetLocalCaretPosition();

int pos = GetCharacterIndexFromPosition(mPos);
Debug.Log("pos = " + pos);
GameObject.FindWithTag("canvas").GetComponent<Calculator>().carretPostion = pos;
GameObject.FindWithTag("canvas").GetComponent<Calculator>().carretVector = mPos;

base.OnPointerUp(eventData);
}
public Vector2 GetLocalCaretPosition()
{
// if (isFocused)
// {
TextGenerator gen = m_TextComponent.cachedTextGenerator;
UICharInfo charInfo = gen.characters[caretPosition];
float x = (charInfo.cursorPos.x + charInfo.charWidth) / m_TextComponent.pixelsPerUnit;
float y = (charInfo.cursorPos.y) / m_TextComponent.pixelsPerUnit;
Debug.Log("x=" + x + "y=" + y);
return new Vector2(x, y);
// }
// else
// return new Vector2(0f, 0f);
}

private int GetCharacterIndexFromPosition(Vector2 pos)
{
TextGenerator gen = m_TextComponent.cachedTextGenerator;

if (gen.lineCount == 0)
return 0;

int line = GetUnclampedCharacterLineFromPosition(pos, gen);
if (line < 0)
return 0;
if (line >= gen.lineCount)
return gen.characterCountVisible;

int startCharIndex = gen.lines[line].startCharIdx;
int endCharIndex = GetLineEndPosition(gen, line);

for (int i = startCharIndex; i < endCharIndex; i++)
{
if (i >= gen.characterCountVisible)
break;

UICharInfo charInfo = gen.characters[i];
Vector2 charPos = charInfo.cursorPos / m_TextComponent.pixelsPerUnit;

float distToCharStart = pos.x - charPos.x;
float distToCharEnd = charPos.x + (charInfo.charWidth / m_TextComponent.pixelsPerUnit) - pos.x;
if (distToCharStart < distToCharEnd)
return i;
}

return endCharIndex;
}

private int GetUnclampedCharacterLineFromPosition(Vector2 pos, TextGenerator generator)
{

// transform y to local scale
float y = pos.y * m_TextComponent.pixelsPerUnit;
float lastBottomY = 0.0f;

for (int i = 0; i < generator.lineCount; ++i)
{
float topY = generator.lines[i].topY;
float bottomY = topY - generator.lines[i].height;

// pos is somewhere in the leading above this line
if (y > topY)
{
// determine which line we're closer to
float leading = topY - lastBottomY;
if (y > topY - 0.5f * leading)
return i - 1;
else
return i;
}

if (y > bottomY)
return i;

lastBottomY = bottomY;
}

// Position is after last line.
return generator.lineCount;
}

private static int GetLineEndPosition(TextGenerator gen, int line)
{
line = Mathf.Max(line, 0);
if (line + 1 < gen.lines.Count)
return gen.lines[line + 1].startCharIdx - 1;
return gen.characterCountVisible;
}

}
```

Comment: I'm making a calculator and I have the same problem you had. Can you tell me how to apply this code and how to change carretposition of inputfield when click the custom keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
TouchScreenKeyboard keyboard;

void Update()
{
    if (keyboard != null)
    {
        if (Input.deviceOrientation == DeviceOrientation.FaceDown)
            keyboard.active = false;
        if (Input.deviceOrientation == DeviceOrientation.FaceUp)
            keyboard.active = true;
    }
}
```

it will retrieve the TouchScreenKeyboard and after that, you can active or deactive it as you want.